Revit, SectionView (viewing from above) created from FloorPlan is mirrored
I try to create a SectionView out of FloorPlan. The viewing direction is from above, actually the same as in the FloorPlan. The SectionView created is mirrored:
resulting section view
Here is my code:
        //uiapp is UIApplication, ass is input assembley, danglerad is input angle radian
        FamilyInstance fibox = GetPlaceholderBoxFromAssembly(uiapp, ass);
        double dw = bbox.Max.Subtract(bbox.Min).X;
        double dd = bbox.Max.Subtract(bbox.Min).Y;
        double dh = bbox.Max.Subtract(bbox.Min).Z;

            snameprefix = "up";

            max_pt = new XYZ(dw, dd, dh); 
            min_pt = new XYZ(-dw, -dd, -dh);

            bbox.Max = max_pt;
            bbox.Min = min_pt;

            trans = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform.CreateRotation(XYZ.BasisZ, danglerad);
          trans.Origin = mid_pt;

        try
        {
            bbox.Transform = trans; 
        }
        catch { }           
            
            
        using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document, "CreateSecPlan"))
        {
            tr.Start();
                viewsec = ViewSection.CreateSection(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document, viewfamtypeid, bbox); 
                viewsec.Name += $"_{ass.Name}_{snameprefix}";
                viewsec.DisplayStyle = DisplayStyle.HLR;
                viewsec.DetailLevel = ViewDetailLevel.Fine;
                viewsec.ViewTemplateId = templid;
                viewsec.Scale = iscale;
                
                viewsec.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SECTION_COARSER_SCALE_PULLDOWN_METRIC).Set(1);

                tr.Commit();                    

        }
        
        using (Transaction t3 = new Transaction(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document, "MirrorView"))
        {
            t3.Start();

            Plane pln = Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(viewsec.ViewDirection, viewsec.Origin);
            ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElements(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document, new List<ElementId>     { viewsec.Id }, pln, false);
            t3.Commit();
        }

Can anyone tell me, what's wrong here?
I've also tried:
viewsec = ViewSection.CreateDetail(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document, viewfamtypeid, bbox);
and view's CropBoxElement mirroring. Both to no avail.

Check it out in the user interface. The API is just a wrapper around the UI, and the functionality is the same. You can probably correct it somehow or other in the UI, e.g., by reversing the view direction, and then reproduce the same (fixed) situation programmatically in the API.

Hi, I've gone it thru with our Drafstmen and get the code that functions ath the very end:
instead of

trans = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform.CreateRotation(XYZ.BasisZ, danglerad);
one should take:
Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform trans = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform.Identity;
trans.BasisX = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform.CreateRotation(XYZ.BasisZ, danglerad).OfVector(XYZ.BasisX);
trans.BasisZ = -XYZ.BasisZ;
trans.BasisY = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform.CreateRotation(XYZ.BasisZ, Math.PI + danglerad).OfVector(XYZ.BasisY);
